# Editar información dentro de una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información la cargo por `BDD`, necesito poder agregar o modificar el texto en la columna de comentario por lo cual cree una columna columna y dentro de ella es necesario dar click en el icono el cual despliega un `PopUp` el cual muestra una caja de texto para agregar o modificar la información.

Quisiera saber si es posible dar un click en el texto de la columna comentario y posteriormente modificarlo o agregarlo, creo que es una manera mas practica a comparación de la funcionalidad que ya tengo.

Comment: que estas utilizando para cargar la tabla ?
Rest, C#, Java, Ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Has probado con contenteditable ?
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

```
<p contenteditable="true">Editable.</p>
```

No sé si a eso te refieres.

Comment: bien, pero falta la parte para enviarla de vuelta al servidor para guardar los datos

Comment: Puedes mostrar tú código para tener más claro que quieres hacer.